# How to target css for ie7 standards

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

Like many others I really hate developing for IE7 and as usually I use the method below:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../res/styleie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

This targets the browser version IE7 but not the document standard for IE7.

I need a method for the users that uses a later version of IE(IE8, 9, 10) but have their browser set to use IE7 standards. Is there a way to detect that instead of just detecting the browser version?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the approach of attaching a class attribute to the HTML:

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

This way you can target your CSS with an IE prefix, for example:

```
.ie7 .selector {
  properties
 }
```

This approach works when, for example, I'm running IE10 in IE7 mode

Comment: In IE10 for example, when you hit F12 to open the developer tools, then change the Browser Mode and Document Mode to IE7, are you seeing the ie7 class being applied to the HTML element?

Comment: No it is not beeing applied when I run for example Browsermode: ie8 and ie7 mode, It is beeing applied when I use Browsermode ie7

Comment: Aah I see. Unfortunately you can't use conditional comments in this case as it can't distinguish compatibility mode versus native. You'd probably have to use JavaScript document.documentMode, so it'd be something like if(document.documentMode && document.documentMode < 8) {...} - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28VS.85%29.aspx for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html lang="en" class="no-js ie lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html lang="en" class="no-js ie lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html lang="en" class="no-js ie lt-ie10 lt-ie9 ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html lang="en" class="no-js ie lt-ie10 ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 10]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie10"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
```

put this code after your

now your css for ie7 is

```
.ie7 .yourclass-or-id{
}
```

now your css for ie8 is

```
.ie8 .yourclass-or-id{
}
```

now your css for ie9 is

```
.ie9 .yourclass-or-id{
}
```

now your css for ie10 is

```
.ie10 .yourclass-or-id{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE8+ in compatibility mode [will send back `Trident` in the User-Agent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx), which [does not appear in IE7 User-Agent strings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/04/27/412813.aspx?Redirected=true)

More generally, there are [libraries that already use this logic](http://cssuseragent.org/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply but this doesn't seem to work either. The script adds a class to the html-tag on load and wen I use Browsermode ie8 with ie7 standards the class added is "ua-ie-8". When I use Browsermode ie7 the class is "ua-ie-7". When I use Browsermode ie8 and ie8 standards the classes are the same as when I use Browsermode ie8 with ie7 standards

Comment: @PaperThick can you confirm that IE8 with IE7 standards shows a different useragent from IE7 ?

Comment: I'm guessing that the last three classes added the the html tag is the ones that defines the browser and for ie 8 with ie7 standards they are "ua-ie ua-ie-8 ua-ie-8-0" and for ie7 with ie7 standards the are "ua-ie ua-ie-7 ua-ie-7-0"